How does AXI write-strobe wstrb[7:0] get mapped into wstrb[3:0]?
The master is 64 bits and transfers aligned byte data to the 32-bit slave bus.
Especially, I randomly used the byte-aligned wstrb[7:0] value according to the AXI specification.
Master:

awaddr[35:0] = 0x642_0860
awburst[1:0] = 0x1
awlen[7:0]   = 0x3
awsize[2:0]  = 0x1
wdata[63:0]  = 0xefa9_d2c9_2f96_d822
wstrb[7:0]   = 0x3 0x30 0xc0 0x0c


Slave

awaddr[35:0] = 0x642_0860
awburst[1:0] = 0x1
awlen[7:0]   = 0x3
awsize[2:0]  = 0x1
wdata[31:0]  = 0xd822 0x0  0xefa9_0000 0x0
wstrb[3:0]   = 0x3    0x0  0xc         0x0

As you can see, the Slave's wdata[31:0] does not correctly get receivied the data from Master.
Especially  Master's wdata[47:40] and wdata[39:32] didn't get correctly to Slave.
I'm confused that it works when Master's wstrb[7:0]= 0xf0; and 0x0f. But, when I choose different wstrb value, then slave can't get data.
As I understand that the write data channel carries the write data from the master to the slave and includes:
• the data bus, that can be 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, or 1024 bits wide
• a byte lane strobe signal for every eight data bits, 
  indicating which bytes of the data are valid. Write data channel 
  information is always treated as buffered, so that the master can 
  perform write transactions without slave acknowledgement of previous 
  write transactions.

How does wstrb[7:0] get mapped into wstrb[3:0]?

Is there any specific rule for this case?
Could you guide me please?
After conducting several experiments, I discovered that when a 64-bit Master sends data to a 32-bit slave, the data must be sent in 32-bit chunks. Since the Master is 64-bit, the wstrb can either be 8'hf or 8'hf0.
When I send the 64-bit data with wstrb = 'hf0 first and then wstrb = 'hf, the slave doesn't receive the data correctly. However, when I send the data with wstrb = 'hf first and then wstrb = 'hf0, the slave successfully receives the data.
Initially, I believed that as long as the 64-bit data was split into two 32-bit segments and the wstrb was aligned with the 32-bit boundaries, any combination of wstrb values should work. But based on my experiments, it appears that the wstrb needs to send the lower 32 bits first, followed by the upper 32 bits. Is this the expected behavior? Does the lower 32 bits always need to be transmitted before the upper 32 bits?
Why can't I send wstrb = 8'h1001_1010 first and then wstrb = 8'h0110_0101? I’m really confused and would appreciate some clarification on this.
In the specification there are some description

As you can see, first transfer can be upper 32 bits.

The master has a 64-bit wide data bus and 8-bit wide strobe signal.  Both are outputs from the master.
The slave has a 32-bit wide data bus and 4-bit wide strobe signal.  Both are inputs to the slave.
When the 2 are connected, only half of the bits from the master are connected to the slave.  This implies that there should be a multiplexer for each signal.  For example:

for the 1st transfer, the upper 32 bits of data are selected in the mux to drive the 32-bit slave data input
for the 2nd transfer, the lower 32 bits of data are selected in the mux to drive the 32-bit slave data input

From your previous questions, I know you are familiar with Verilog syntax:
wire [63:0] wdata_m;
wire [31:0] wdata_s = (first) ? wdata_m[63:32] : wdata_m[31:0];

The same is true for the strobe signals.  The strobes indicate which of the data bytes are valid.  Therefore, you must maintain coherency between the data and strobes.  When the upper data bits are used for the 1st transfer, the upper strobe bits must be used as well ([7:4]).
wire [7:0] wstrb_m;
wire [3:0] wstrb_s = (first) ? wstrb_m[7:4] : wstrb_m[3:0];

